# Google play integrity api issue

Tags: android, google-api

I am migrating my app from Google play safety net api to Integrity api, but getting below error from api-

com.google.android.play.core.integrity.IntegrityServiceException: -12: Integrity API error (-12): Unknown internal Google server error.
Retry with an exponential backoff. Consider filing a bug if fails consistently
(https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/integrity/model/IntegrityErrorCode.html#GOOGLE_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE).

Below is my code sample-

```
String str = "MTY1Mzk3NTAxMjYwNjE2NTM5NzUwMTI2MDc=";
byte[] strBytes = android.util.Base64.decode(str, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
byte[] encoded = android.util.Base64.encode(
            strBytes, android.util.Base64.URL_SAFE | android.util.Base64.NO_PADDING | android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);
String nonce =  new String(encoded);
IntegrityManager integrityManager = 
                 IntegrityManagerFactory.create(getApplicationContext());
Task<IntegrityTokenResponse> integrityTokenResponse =
            integrityManager
                    .requestIntegrityToken(
                            IntegrityTokenRequest.builder().setNonce(nonce).build());

    integrityTokenResponse.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<IntegrityTokenResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<IntegrityTokenResponse> task) {}
    });

    integrityTokenResponse.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {}
    });
```

Any help will be appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've seen that problem, and for me the solution was to include the Cloud project number into the integrity request:

```
IntegrityTokenRequest.builder()
            .setCloudProjectNumber([YOUR_CLOUD_PROJECT_NUMBER])
            .setNonce(nonce)
            .build()
```

I build an SDK, so that's the only solution available, however there is an [alternative](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup#apps-on-google-play), if you have an app distributed through the Play Store:

> In the Play Console, navigate to the Release section of the left menu. Go to Setup > App integrity. Select the Integrity API tab to get started.

Comment: Can you kindly share the complete code to implement Play Integrity API for apps directly distributed as APKs

Answer (score 2):

I am also migrating for safetynet check. Implemented as above bit recieving exception as below
W/System.err: com.google.android.play.core.integrity.IntegrityServiceException: -8: Integrity API error (-8): The calling app is making too many requests to the API and hence is throttled.
W/System.err: Retry with an exponential backoff.
W/System.err:  (https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/integrity/model/IntegrityErrorCode.html#TOO_MANY_REQUESTS).
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.play.core.integrity.zzs.zzb(com.google.android.play:integrity@@1.0.0:5)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.play.integrity.internal.zzg.zza(com.google.android.play:integrity@@1.0.0:2)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.play.integrity.internal.zzb.onTransact(com.google.android.play:integrity@@1.0.0:3)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1187)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1146)

Comment: hi, have you got any solution for error of "(-8): The calling app is making too many requests to the API"?

Comment: I am also facing same error "calling app is too many request to the API" Any one has solution for the same?

Comment: Anybody? having the same issue here too. Is there any other place that I should connect my SDK with GC? Can't see any of my requests in the metrics so I assume they are not even reaching there.